# OL3 - Draw rectangle using single drag movement

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm looking for a way to draw a rectangle in a single drag movement, so the user click and hold the mouse pressed then move the mouse and the rectangle is painting as he go and the drawing is finished when he stop pressing the mouse.
Currently it's done using mouse click -> drag -> mouse click again to finish, not that intuitive.

I'm using the latest OpenLayers 3.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-rotate-and-zoom.html?q=interaction+drag

Answer (score 1):

The functionality asked for is already present in latest openlayers version (v3.19). Use `ol.interaction.Draw.createBox()` to create a rectangle with 2 clicks one for start and another for end. See the below example for more details
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html?q=draw
You can create your style for the rectangle by creating style object and declaring it in ol.interaction.Draw().

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the built-in interaction use an instance of https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/interaction/dragzoom.js but pass in an option/condition to not use the shift key.  Here are the conditions https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/events/condition.js

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [DragBox](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.DragBox.html) interaction? This will give the user an outline of the box as they are drawing it with click, drag, and release being the interaction.